# Core audio user space driver, How to start a xcode project?

Tags: core-audio

I am trying to start a project to create a virtual audio device which will mirror the system's default sound output, I want to create a .driver to place under /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL , but I am not able to figure out how to setup the .driver project, I could find Kext, Dext, but not driver,am I missing something. I use xcode 11.3.

If I choose IOkit Driver the product is a .kext.
If i choose Driverkit Driver the output is a .dext.

I am not able to get .driver as output.[the project types I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ob48.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by creating a new XCode project with a Bundle template. After clicking next you can choose the extension you want to give the plugin.

Or you could add a new target with the Bundle template in an existing XCode project which will give you the same options as mentioned above.

[This](https://github.com/betabandido/mac2rpi_coreaudio_plugin) project should give you a very good example.